# provider is not compatible with the version of oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle10g, oracle11g

i created a c# console application in a system by using the oracle 11g dll.

now i want to execute its console application exe file on another system having oracle10g installed.

both system are connected through LAN network.

Comment: Details, details. There are multiple providers for Oracle. Which error on which system, installed DLLs, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can change your app.config on the system with 10g installed.
Here is an example that you can start with.  The newVersion will need to match the version installed on your machine.  We use this to use 10g on 32bit machines and 11g on 64bit machines.  The application is built against 10g.  You may have issues if you are using 11g features and then use the 10g driver.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342" culture="neutral" processorArchitecture="amd64"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.2.0.100" newVersion="10.2.0.100"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.2.0.100" newVersion="10.2.0.100"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```